# Аббревиатура Г.Ф.З

Tags: история, аббревиатура

Подскажите что до революции обозначала аббревиатура Г.Ф.З. на пряжке ремня?

Comment: Если эта аббревиатура на пряжке, то желательно знать в каком месте найдена эта пряжка, а ещё лучше приложить её фотографию. Но сразу скажу, вопрос не по теме форума и вам лучше обратится в сообщество коллекционеров. Скорее всего это пряжка какого-то учебного заведения или тюрьмы.

Comment: @ЯнаБеликова Сжатая информация о некоторых видах дореволюционных пряжек есть здесь: http://kopmonet.ru/сопутка/пряжки-царские/

Answer (score 3):

Возможно,  Государственный фарфоровый завод, но он назывался Г.Ф.З. с 1917 года, до этого  Императорский фарфоровый завод в Санкт-Петербурге, основан в 1744 году. ([Императорский фарфоровый завод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4))

В 1935 — отменены точки в написании аббревиатур из заглавных букв.   https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE_1956_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Тогда это сложная задача, Вам лучше обратиться на тематические форумы, например: КЛЕЙМА/Расшифровка производителей Царских пряжек. https://vk.com/topic-105227068_32940570

До революции 1917 года в России все почти ходили в форме, а стало быть, и в ремнях с пряжками. Не только военные, но и гражданские ведомства имели свою форму и свои ремни с особыми пряжками.  Ремни с пряжками носили гимназисты, учащиеся реальных и кадетских училищ, студенты. Даже профессора носили форму. Свои пряжки, каждую со своей символикой имели пожарники и почтальоны, железнодорожники и инженеры. Каждое инженерное ведомство имело особую форму и особый ремень с пряжкой. Инженеры горные - свою пряжку, инженеры-строители - свою, и так далее.

http://www.mnemosyne.ru/handmade/buckle.html

Comment: Буквы Г.Ф.З. на пряжке ремня.

Comment: Именно с точками.

Comment: По поводу униформы. Её действительно  имели тогдашние бюджетники -  государевы (государственные) служащие, студенты и гимназисты - и при этом обычно она не была какой-то специфической для конкретного учреждения. Но уж никак  не рабочие частных заводов и фабрик..

Answer (score 1):

Уже сказали, что без фото можно только гадать. Да и вопрос не совсем по профилю ресурса.

Из всех возможных именно *дореволюционных* аббревиатур самое правдоподобное - **"Городницкий фарфоровый завод".** Сочетапние ФЗ очень специфично для дореволюционных обозначений, а из всех фарфоровых и фаянсовых заводов на букву Г - Городницкий самый известный.

Но появление такого сокращение на "официальной" пряжке весьма сомнительно, ведь это предполагает наличие какой-то специальной униформы, а таковая, помимо армейских частей, министерств и университетов, была только в отдельных казенных заведениях... 
Так что наиболее правдоподобный вариант тот, что эта пряжка - самоделка с каким угодно смыслом, вплоть до  инициалов дамы сердца. 
Короче, нужна картинка.

// ===
Добавлю. Я подразумеваю, что Г.Ф.З. - это именно **надпись** на пряжке, а не клеймо производителя, в последнем случае даже гадать бесполезно, не будучи знатоком предмета.

Answer (score 1):

Гжельский фарфоровый завод.

Крупнейшее предприятие народных художественных промыслов России. Основано в 1818 г.

http://moscow.cataloxy.ru/firms/www.farfor-gzhel.ru.htm